# Canvas is clipped when size is too big

Tags: wpf, canvas

I am using a canvas with the an `ImageBrush` to dispaly an image. I am setting the size of the canvas to the original size of the image so I can get the coordinates when I move the mouse etc.

The problem is that when I put the canvas in a control (`Grid` for example) with a smaller size the `Canvas` is clipped.

```
  <Grid>
    <Canvas Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" >
        <Canvas.Background>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"/>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
```

Is there a way to keep the canvas size without being clipped?

Comment: Either put the Canvas in a Viewbox, so that it shrinks to fit the Grid size, or use a ScrollViewer to make the Canvas scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been meaning to dig deeper in to the source to work out where the clipping occurs for a while now, but never get around to doing it.  I've been using a not-so-nice trick of inserting a `Canvas` into the visual tree when this happens as a workaround.

There are a number of controls that clip the child visuals; `Grid`, `StackPanel`, etc.  As I mentioned the usual quick fix is to use a `Canvas` after the container that causes the clip.

In your snippet are there more containers higher up the visual tree?

If the depth was actually something like this:-

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" >
            <Canvas.Background>
              <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Then this might cause clipping.  If you insert another `Canvas` further up the visual tree then this clipping is removed.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas>
        <Grid>
            <Canvas Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" >
                <Canvas.Background>
                  <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}}"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

This workaround can then become problematic if it alters other layout needs for other controls.